# Word for Someone Who Watches Mountain Weather

Tags: word-choice

I've been working on a paper regarding the Himalays. As part of that, I've been learning about sherpas. I feel like I see these kinds of people watching or monitoring mountains. Either for weather or signs of trouble. I'm trying to figure out if these people that watch these mountains have a title or a name? I'd like to use it in my paper. Does anyone know what these people are called?

Thanks

Comment: ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎Unicorns.

Comment: they are sherpas.

Comment: It may be better to ask on a more appropriate Q&A site. Could be off topic on ELU.

Answer (score 2):

In the United States, such people are called *spotters*.  They are activated when the National Weather Service believes there to be a risk of fire, tornadoes, severe thunderstorms, etc.  There are especially common in mountain areas at risk for wildfire during Red Flag days, but also get activated for other forms a severe weather.

Comment: *Spotters* are not a 'kind of people' who culturally watch the mountain weather -- I could be a 'spotter' if I wanted.

Comment: @Kris Nothing says “culturally”.  
Anyway, you couldn’t be a *trained spotter* without training.  It’s normally a volunteer but trained position, but in some cases it is a paid one.

Comment: 'Sherpas' are. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherpa_people